# Is there a function that says whether a word is good or bad?

Tags: spell-checking

That is, one that would make `:echo good('crazy')` print '1'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`spellbadword`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#spellbadword%28%29) function:

```
spellbadword([{sentence}])
    ...
    With argument: The result is the first word in {sentence} that
    is badly spelled.  If there are no spelling mistakes the
    result is an empty string.

    The return value is a list with two items:
    - The badly spelled word or an empty string.
    - The type of the spelling error:
            "bad"           spelling mistake
            "rare"          rare word
            "local"         word only valid in another region
            "caps"          word should start with Capital
    Example: 
            echo spellbadword("the quik brown fox")
           ['quik', 'bad']
```

So:

```
function Good(word)
   return len(spellbadword(a:word)[0]) == 0
endfunction
```

Then:

```
:echo Good('crazy')
1
:echo Good('crzy')
0
```